# get top posts link by add_query_arg() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

in wordpress we have `add_query_arg()` function to generat a url query from public *key* and *value* .

i retrive the **cat** link from query with `add_query_arg()` function like this :

```
$retrive ='424'; //my custom cat id .
$postnumber = '5';   
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('showposts' => $postnumber , 'cat' => $retrive));
$query_name = get_cat_name($retrive);
$key = 'cat';
$value = $retrive;
// generat query link
$query_link= esc_url( add_query_arg( $key , $value ,site_url('/') ) );
echo '<a class="btn btn-lg btn-blue" href="'.$query_link.'">'.$query_name.'</a>';
```

now ,i want the link of "**top**" and "**rand**" post with `add_query_arg()` function.
this is my query's:

```
$top_query = new WP_Query(array('meta_key'=>'post_views_count','orderby'=>'meta_value_num','showposts'=>$postnumber,'order'=>'DESC'));
$key = ?;
$value = ?;

$rand_query = new WP_Query(array('showposts' => $postnumber , 'orderby' => 'rand'));
$key = ?;
$value = ?;
```

*(i need this links for my custom tab_widget plugin that user can see the link of other post of current tab.)*

how can do this ?

Comment: If you just want the *link*, then `$top_query_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'orderby', 'views', site_url('/') ) );` (or change `views` to `top`) and `$rand_query_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'orderby', 'rand', site_url('/') ) );` ..

Comment: thanks . But it doesnt work for me ! are you tested it?

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work". And how exactly are you going to use the links? What are their relation to the 'tab_widget' plugin?

Comment: when creat your link this not affect and dont work .
in the bottom of all tab i need a "More" link that linked to other posts of this query
i do it for cat query . But i need that for top and rand query post .